# How to make aritmetic operations on Balance numbers to avoid overflow in NEAR smart contracts?

Tags: rust, nearprotocol

I want to do the following operation on `Balance` (`u128`) numbers in NEAR smart contract using Rust:

```
a*b / (a+b)
```

To avoid overflow I need to convert the type to a type that supports bigger numbers. What's the proper way to do it?

I found a `construct_uint!` macro. Is this a proper way to do or there is a better way?

```
construct_uint! {
    /// 256-bit unsigned integer.
    pub struct u256(4);

}

...
let aB = u256::from(a);
let bB = u256::from(b);
return (aB*bB / (aB+bB)).as_u128();
```

Comment: It's the way we do this in lockup contract. You can see it in action here: https://github.com/near/core-contracts/blob/215d4ed2edb563c47edd961555106b74275c4274/lockup/src/getters.rs#L140-L148

Answer (score 1):

For the underflow part, please see `saturating_sub`:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u128.html#method.saturating_sub

Comment: Thanks. The question is rather about overflows and u256 construction.